# Correct way of getting count on FK

Tags: django

What is the correct way of getting the 'contact' **count** from within my 'Group'?

I was thinking of just creating a new method within 'group' and filter(), but this means hitting the db again which seems bad, right?

```
class GroupManager(models.Manager):

    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(user=user,)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True,)

    #FK
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user")

    objects = GroupManager()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts.views.group', args=[str(self.id)])


class Contact(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    #FK
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_object.contact_set.count()` should do it. Django creates the relation by adding `_set` to the end of the foreign key's model name.

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) on related objects for more info.